# tensorboard throws 404 not found with jupyterhub on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, http-status-code-404, tensorboard, jupyterhub

tried every solution on google to render tensorboard on jupyterhub notebook on kubernetes.
it just keeps throwing 404 error.
even made the code change in tensorboard/notebook.py as mentioned in https://code.tubitv.com/jupyterhub-on-kubernetes-da8940488529
and here is the image i’m using for the user profile

display_name: “tensorflow environment”
description: “The tensorflow image!”
kubespawner_override:
image: jupyter/tensorflow-notebook:3b1f4f5e6cc1
i’m trying to run without GPU. the same image works fine if i bring it up with docker. Tensorboard renders. But on K8S with jupyterhub, it just does not render tensorboard
please help with this issue

Comment: What is your infrastructure? Could you add your deployment and service? How do you expose your app?

Comment: my k8s is on GKE. used the https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-jupyterhub/setup-jupyterhub.html to bring up the hub. not using DNS yet as i'm using the setup for POC. notebooks load correctly. tensorflow works fine. but when it comes to tensorboard, it just does not load and keeps on throwing 404.https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_in_notebooks